# Issue with Android Service in SDK >= 26

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm creating an application which send notifications to the user even when app is killed from the process or in background. Actually in the Android versions with SDK >= 26 I'm using foreground services.
For showing notifications, I have a service (DatasNotification) which starts an asyncTask (HttpRequest) for making an http request and the asynctask at the end of the conditions starts a new service that show the notification.
When my app goes in background, I have a system notification that said: my application is draining battery.
During my analysis I understood that this system notification is generated by DatasNotification service.

This is my DatasNotification code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new HttpRequest(getApplicationContext(), 0).execute();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Is there any solution for running a background service in sdk >= 26?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an Oreo (API26-27) specific feature to show a system notification that an "[app] is using battery” when an app was running background services. You’ll notice that you won’t be receiving the same warning in devices running P (API28) or Android 10 (API 29), since that warning was removed/disabled altogether. I don’t think there’s anything you can change in your app to prevent that warning from showing in Oreo devices unless you can get rid of your (background) services altogether.

A user can disable that warning from showing by doing the following:

> 1. Unlock your device running Android Oreo
> 2. Swipe down on the
>      notification shade, fully exposing the “using battery” notification
> 3. Long press on the notification until it changes and shows a toggle
> 4. Tap on the toggle, making sure that it’s grayed out
> 5. Select Done to
>      disable the “using battery” notification

([source](https://9to5google.com/2017/10/26/how-to-disable-android-oreo-using-battery-notification-android-basics/))